# Yes/No : Is $g$ Riemann integrable on $[0,1.571]?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Define  $g : [0,1.571] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ { g }(x)=\begin{cases} \sin   x \quad \text{if}\quad x \in [0,1/2] \\\cos x \quad \text{if}\quad x \in (1/2,1] \\ \tan x \quad \text {if} \quad x \in (1,1.571]\end{cases} $$

**My question** : Is $g$  Riemann integrable  on $[0,1.571]?$

**My attempt** : I think **Yes**

$[0,1.571] = [0,1/2]\cup[1/2,1]\cup [1,1.571]$. Now by using  the Darboux's concept  , i,e if $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ iff there exists a partition of $[a,b]$ whose sum of areas under curves = $\sum_1^n M_j \varDelta x_j < \varepsilon$.

By Darboux's idea $g$ is integrable on $[0,1/2],[1/2,1]$ and $[1,1.571]$

This implies the existence of partitions $\mathcal P_1, \mathcal P_2$  and $\mathcal P_3$ of each interval such that

$$U(\mathcal P_1, g)-L (\mathcal P_1, g)< \epsilon$$

$$U(\mathcal P_2, g)-L (\mathcal P_2, g)< \epsilon$$

and $$U(\mathcal P_3, g)-L (\mathcal P_3, g)< \epsilon$$

Also, $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal P_1 \cup \mathcal P_2 \cup \mathcal P_3$

$$\implies  U(\mathcal P, g)-L (\mathcal P, g)< \epsilon$$

Therefore $g$ is Riemann integrable  on $[0,1.571]$

Is it true ?

Comment: I don't have a formal proof, but as the function has a finite number of discontinuities and it is finite in the interval, we can say that the function is Riemann integrable in the interval.

Comment: More generally a function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: @Shahab but $\tan (3.14) \cong \infty$

Comment: @jasmine by $3.14$ do you mean $\pi$

Comment: @Peter i edited

Comment: @Nyra Actually, i thought that  $\pi/2 = 3.14$

Comment: π/2<1.571, so it isn't.

Comment: A function defined piecewise on intervals is Riemann integrable if and only if it is Riemann integrable on each interval.

Comment: okay@ThomasAndrews Actually ,i thought that   $g$ is Darboux integrable

Comment: @jasmine Hard to tell if you are joking, but Darboux and Riemann are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1.571>\frac\pi2$ and $\tan$ isn't Riemann (or Lebesgue) integrable in a any neighbourhood of $\frac\pi2$. Therefore $g$ isn't Riemann integrable.

Comment: okay@Saucy O'Path    that means $|g|\ge1 \implies g$ is unbounded. Am i right ?

Comment: There are some $x\in [0,1.571]\setminus\{\pi/2\}$ such that $\lvert g(x)\rvert<1$. It is true that $g$ is unbounded on its domain.

Comment: Technically, you also need $1<\pi/2.$ But that is obvious.

Comment: @jasmine $|g|>1$ does not mean $g$ is unbounded. You need, for any $n,$ some $x$ so that $|g(x)|>n$ to know $g$ is unbounded. $g(x)=3+\cos x>1,$ but $g(x)\leq 5,$ so $g$ is bounded.

Comment: Okay @ThomasAndrews  but I think  $g(x) \le 4$ because  $\cos x \le 1$

Comment: Sure, but also $g(x)\leq 5.$ You don't need a minimum upper bound to get a function is bounded. @jasmine (I chose $5$ originally because I was going to write $<6,$ but changed it to $\leq 5.$)